# How to get the class that the method is defined, not that of the instance that the method is called?

Tags: objective-c, ios, reflection

[self class] returns the Class of the instance of the method being called, but is there a way to get the Class that the method is defined? Suppose Class B extends A, and b is an instance of B, I want a method in A that returns A not B, even when called from b.

**edited:**

I trying to create a NSObject category that has -(void)releaseProperties method, which fetches all properties defined in that class and set nil for the non-readonly object properties.

```
- (void)releaseProperties {
    unsigned int c = 0;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &c);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];
        NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];
        NSString *propertyType = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getAttributes(property)];

        if([propertyType hasPrefix:@"T@"] // is an object
           && [propertyType rangeOfString:@",R,"].location == NSNotFound // not readonly
           ) {
            [self setValue:nil forKey:propertyName];
            NSLog(@"%@.%@ = %@", NSStringFromClass(cls), propertyName, [self valueForKey:propertyName]);
        }
    }
    free(properties);
}
```

I want to use this method in the dealloc method, but class_copyPropertyList([self class], &c) will not return properties defined in it's superclass, so the super-dealloc chain doesn't work well. So, instead of passing [self class], I wanted to pass the class that the specific dealloc method is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class A can just provide a method like:

```
- (Class) classA
{
    return [A class];
}
```

That's not generalizable, but your question insists on a non-generalizable answer.

It's a pretty bizarre thing to want. It suggests a problem with your design. May I ask why you want it? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You could pass the class in to the `-releaseProperties` method as a parameter. In the caller, say `-[MyClass dealloc]`, it would do `[self releaseProperties:[MyClass class]]`. There's certainly no way that `-releaseProperties` can tell on its own which method called it and what class defined that method.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a direct way of doing this, but you can call `class_getMethodImplementation_stret` with the current class to get the function pointer for the method that would be called.  Then walk your superclasses, calling the same function with them until it returns something different.  The previous superclass will be the one that is providing the implementation for your class.

**Edit:** Sorry, I may have misread the question.  If you are looking for the first superclass in the hierarchy that defines a method with that signature, then you can just walk the superclasses calling `respondsToSelector:` until one of them doesn't.  The method I describe above is to find the superclass providing the *implementation* that is inherited, not the *definition*.

For example, class `A` could define `foo:`, then class `B` (which is a subclass of `A`) could override it, then class `C` (which is a subclass of `B`) could ask where `foo:` comes from.  If you want the class that provides the definition, you want `A`, and should use the second approach I describe.  If you want the class that provides the implementation, you want `B` and should use the first approach I describe.

Comment: This could work. You have to link against `libobjc.A.dylib` and `#import "objc/runtime.h"` to use `class_getMethodImplementation_stret`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that [`[super class]`](http://paikialog.wordpress.com/2011/01/12/super-in-objective-c/) might work for you.

And if you call "`[super ...`" (fill in the blank with whatever you want to call) within B, you'll be calling into a method that lives in A.

Comment: I think this won't work with more than two layers of abstraction.

Comment: Hmmmm.  I +1'd the (very interesting) question so it'll get more attention, but perhaps I mis-understood what Taketo was asking for?